# TWTeetComposeViewController execute custom code after posting a new tweet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

So, using the new Twitter framework in iOS5, we can simply post Twitter updates with this simple code:

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Tweeting from Steamerduck :)"];
    [controller presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
}
```

However, I would like to execute some custom code after a user clicks on send here:

[image]

Is it possible to execute some custom code, some of my own methods after the TWTweetComposeViewController sends a tweet?

Comment: Are you trying to get it to *AUTO* send the tweet? If thats what your trying to do, apple would never allow that...(Spamming and twitting as another person)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a completion handler that gets called after the user is done composing the tweet.  It would look something like this (I haven't had a chance to test this on a device yet):

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Tweeting from Steamerduck :)"];

    // Set a completion handler to be called when the user is done
    // composing their tweet

    [tweetSheet setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
            // Tweet was sent, do something
        } else if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
            // Do something else if the user cancelled

            [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }];

    [controller presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: This is how you do it, just a note, you might need to add the "dismiss code" in the completition handler, or you will end up having to double tap the cancel buton.

Comment: I've added dismiss code to the cancel section of the completion handler

Comment: @mttrb It works but it shows a warning in Xcode: capturing tweetSheet strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle...

Comment: @mttrb Can I have one more question? How can I access the JSON response from the Twitter API in the completion handler.

Comment: I've changed the receiver of dismissModalViewControllerAnimated to be the controller rather than the tweetSheet as this is more correct and will avoid the retain cycle.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe that TWTweetComposeViewController provides any mechanism for you to access information about the tweet that was sent.  You may have to use the lower level TWRequest but this will probably mean you'll have to create your own version of TWTweetComposeViewController.